# How does one add multiple computer names to a custom view in event viewer?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-event-log, eventviewer

I'm trying to create a "Custom View" thru eventviewer on Windows 2k8R2-SP1 to see multiple logs from multiple nodes in a cluster in one view. But it doesn't seem to accept the remote computers' names by ip or by fqdn. Is there a specific way to add the computernames here.

[image]

None of the blogs I came across discussed adding multiple computer names in a custom view.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? It doesn't accept any computer in this field? It doesn't accept if you enter more than one computer name? It ignores the machines defined? It shows an error message - what error?

Comment: @techraf It ignores the machines defined. No errors while entering the names or editing the filter. It just doesn't get the events from the machines. You can repro in a min.

Comment: Again: you ask about "multiple machines". Does it work for you with one machine?

Comment: @techraf Yes it's working with the name of the local machine. But not with the name of a remote machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The custom view will only show events that are in the event viewer, you can't filter to show remote computer events unless you have connected to the remote computer (Right Click on 'Event Viewer' Select 'Connect to another computer' and enter the remote host name in the 'Another Computer' field).

If you want a central repository for all your cluster hosts you will need to configure [event subscriptions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4aa6403f-d4b8-43a4-a70d-ceb7f88c524e). This will allow you to collect events from multiple hosts and then use the custom filter to view more than one host at a time.